# How to dynamically update values to arguments in Python loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Python newbie here:

I'm writing a market simulation in Python using Pysage, and want to generate an arbitrary number of agents (either buyers or sellers) using the `mgr.register_actor()` function, as follows:

```
for name, maxValuation, endowment, id in xrange(5):
    mgr.register_actor(Buyer(name="buyer001", maxValuation=100, endowment=500),"buyer001")
    update name, maxValuation, endowment, id
```

What is a succinct, pythonic way to run that function call so that, each time the loop is run, the values of name, maxValuation, endowment, and id are changed, e.g. to `name="buyer002", name="buyer003"...; maxValuation=95, maxValuation=90...; endowment=450, endowment=400...; "buyer002", "buyer003"...` and so on.

I have tried different for-loops and list comprehensions, but haven't found a way yet to dynamically update the function arguments without running into type issues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepare the `names`, `maxValuations`, and `endowments` as lists (or iterators), then use [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to group corresponding elements together:

```
names=['buyer{i:0>3d}'.format(i=i) for i in range(1,6)]
maxValuations=range(100,75,-5)
endowments=range(500,250,-50)
for name, maxValuation, endowment in zip(names,maxValuations,endowments):
    mgr.register_actor(
        Buyer(name=name, maxValuation=maxValuation, endowment=endowment),name)
```

---

Regarding the format string, `'{i:0>3d}'`:

I refer to this "cheat sheet" when I need to build a format string:

```
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax
replacement_field ::= "{" field_name ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::= (identifier|integer)("."attribute_name|"["element_index"]")* 
attribute_name    ::= identifier
element_index     ::= integer
conversion        ::= "r" | "s"
format_spec       ::= [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][.precision][type]
fill              ::= <a character other than '}'>
align             ::= "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
                      "=" forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any)
                          but before the digits. (for numeric types)
sign              ::= "+" | "-" | " "
                      " " places a leading space for positive numbers
width             ::= integer
precision         ::= integer
type              ::= "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" |
                      "o" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

So, it breaks down like this:

```
   field_name 
  /
{i:0>3d}
    \\\\
     \\\`-type ("d" means integer)
      \\`-width 
       \`-alignment (">" means right adjust)
        `-fill character
```

Comment: +1: I really like the (relatively) new string format() method. I've been mostly stuck in 2.5.x for legacy reasons and haven't re-read the docs for new stuff in 2.6/3.x. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I'm still trying to grapple with how does the '{i:0>3d}' bit works, and will read the format spec mini-language docs.